# Varios IF y operación sumar si conjunto con Validación de datos

Tags: excel, vba

Tengo dos filtros con dos validaciones de datos en dos celdas.
A partir de la selección que el usuario realice, se ejecuta un sumar.si.conjunto en función de una fecha (en una celda en filas) y una tipología en un columnas.

El problema que tengo es que el filtro 1 y el filtro 2 (de la validación de datos) tiene 8 opciones y 3 opciones respectivamente. Por tanto lo he formulado con SI (Y.... ) imaginaros la cantidad de condiciones que he tenido que introducir (casi no entra en el xls). Además en función del filtro, ejecuta el sumar.si.conjunto en una columna u otra.

Me preguntaba antes de meterme en hacer algo con VBA, si podría mejorar el rendimiento o no.
Tarda aproximadamente unos 30 segundos cada vez que cambio de filtros.

Además me vendría alguna ayuda de por donde podría comenzar....

1.Tengo la tabla donde se actualizan los datos:

TIPOLOGIA (columnas) | FECHAS (FILAS).

Lo calculo con un sumar.si.conjunto en función de la tipología y de las fechas. Y tienen los IF.

2. Filtros.
3. Tabla de datos. Origen de los mismos, depende del filtro se coge una columna u otra.

gracias.

Comment: Jesus puedes poner una captura de cómo están los datos? y todas las tipologías que deben salir, si quieres que sea rápido, VBA sería la clave.